# Scroll while dragging

Tags: android, kotlin, scroll, drag-and-drop, scrollview

I have some `TextViews` with drag and drop implemented in Kotlin and I what I would like to do is when I drag one TextView at the bottom of the screen, where a `ScrollView` is located, for it to **scroll** downwards.

[Here is the app design.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HWO1A.png)

As it is shown in the image, I want to drag `TextViews` from the left column (components) and drop then into the right column (boxes). The boxes `LinearLayout` continues off screen, and the point is that I don't want the user to have to scroll to the last box *before* dragging something into it from the "components" LinearLayout.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to answer my own question, the solution i found is this:

```
lowerLimForScroll = (Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.heightPixels * 0.8).toInt()

textView.setOnDragListener { boxContentView, dragEvent -> 
            
    val boxesLayoutCoords = intArrayOf(0, 0)
    // this calculates the x, y of the top left corner of the 
    // ScrollView
    boxContentView.getLocationInWindow(boxesLayoutCoords)
    when (dragEvent.action) {
        DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION -> {
            checkForScroll(dragEvent.y, boxesLayoutCoords[1])
    }
    true
}
```

likewise, i have to do add an on Drag Listener to the scrollView as well because i use dividers and the scrolling stopped when i got out of the scrollview and hovered over the divider which belongs to the ScrollView

```
scrollView.setOnDragListener { _, dragEvent ->

    val boxesLayoutCoords = intArrayOf(0, 0)
    scrollView.getLocationInWindow(boxesLayoutCoords)

    when (dragEvent.action) {
        DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION -> {
            checkForScroll(dragEvent.y, boxesLayoutCoords[1])
        }              
    }
    true
}
```

and finally the checkForScroll function

```
private fun checkForScroll(pointerY: Float, startOfScrollView: Int) {
    /* if the upper limit is passed, meaning a pixel height, scroll up */
    if ((pointerY + startOfScrollView) < upperLimForScroll) {
        findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.boxesScrollView).smoothScrollBy(0, -20)
    }
    /* if the lower limit is passed, meaning a pixel height, scroll down */
    else if (pointerY + startOfScrollView > lowerLimForScroll) {
        findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.boxesScrollView).smoothScrollBy(0, 15)
    }
}
```